# Is it possible to get un-viewed records in CouchDb View?

Tags: couchdb

CouchDB has View to pre-compute data. But as I have learned I have to use key or startkey/endkey to filter view records.

For situation. I have two type of document is Articles save all article & History save user viewed articles, Is it possible to get un-viewed Articles in CouchDb View ?